Date format in Activity
In Marketing Cloud we have a  custom journey activity. We want to add a feature that would add an input for a datetime. We're currently saving it as a string with milliseconds (e.g. 2024-08-31T20:22:00.000Z). In the final step, all values get saved to inArguments via Postmonger.
When checking the saved inArguments, everything looks ok, but once the journey is activated (probably during journey save time), that attribute gets converted to a time format without milliseconds (2024-08-31T20:22:00Z). That change comes from base-model.js and results in a console log with changed attributes (old to new change). And indeed, once the request reaches our execute route, the format is wrong.
Can someone help us understand why it's happening (especially as the date is saved as a string and should be passed as a string). I was under the impression that inArguments would not be altered in any way.
(tried both with a datetime picker and with a generic input element, same behavior with both)
